# argparse optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a following code in python:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a', '--add', dest='name_to_add', help='Add a new group or a role to existing group')
group.add_argument('-u', '--upgrade', dest='name_to_upgrade', help='Upgrade a group with the new version')
group.add_argument('-r', '--remove', dest='name_to_remove', help='Remove a group')
group.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest="list_server_or_group_name", help='Get group or server state/configuration')
```

My problem is with "-l" option. I want to be able to list a specific group and to list all the groups. Currently I do it with:

"python my_script.py -l group_name" - for listing a specific group
and
"python my_script.py -l all" - for listing all the groups.

But I would like to list all the groups just with:
"python my_script.py -l".
How should I change my code in order to be able to run it this way? and how can I check it later in code?

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible with `optparse`.

However, if you switch from `optparse` to `argparse` (since [2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) or [3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)) you can pass [`nargs='?'`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> '?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced.

```
group.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest="list_server_or_group_name",
                   help='Get group or server state/configuration',
                   nargs='?', default=None, const='all')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. For some reason it doesn't work for me. After adding this and running with "-l" option, args.list_server_or_group_name is None for some reason and I expect it to be "all"

Comment: @alexarsh -- Try adding the `const` keyword (e.g. `const = 'all'`) as well.  Most enlighteningly, try a simple program where you add an argument as:  `grp.add_argument('-l',nargs='?',default=None,const='foo')` and then walk through the different options (calling with `-l`, `-l foo` and without `-l`).